# Twitter like url routing in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter, url-routing

I ve seen in twitter, i can get a user view page by just typing in the url say `http://twitter.com/pandiyachendur`. How to do the same with asp.net mvc? I dont know how twitter does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful about the order in which you declare your routes. Since there is no common element to a `/{username}` URL, you need to declare it as the last 'catch-all' route, after all of your specific routes.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(null, "LogIn", new { controller = "Account", action = "LogIn" });
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(null, "LogOut", new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOut" });
// ... other routes go here ...

// Final catch-all route to map /{username} to the Account.Details action.
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(null, "{id}", new { controller = "Account", action = "Details" });
```

It's also worth remembering that you need to extend your validation on usernames to prevent people from choosing names that conflict with the specific routes (e.g. *LogIn*).

Comment: +1 - and validate about any future urls you may want... dangerous territory if you ask me.

Comment: I agree, there's a high maintenance cost associated with this. On the upside, in cases where validation falls short, only the users with route conflicts will exhibit problems. The application will continue to function for non-conflicting users.

If you can think of a better way to achieve the desired routing, please share.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that they have some regular exception that checks the request to see if it matches something that could be a user's profile and then push that request to an appropriate controller action.

They'd likely might list first all of the exceptions are static routes, like "/invitations", and then pass everything else to a default controller action that attempts to display a user's page.